# Expression like "just in time"

Tags: idioms, adverbs, time

I'm looking for an expression. Let me explain:

I have a meeting at certain time. What I want to say is that I will be there in time, but not before. I'll be there too close to time meeting.

I would excuse myself to not arrive with more than enough time. I was thinking in something like `I'll arrive in time` or `just in time` (which both would be true... I guess), but those expressions look to me that I will arrive *some time* before the meeting.  
For instance, if the meeting would be at 19:30, I'll arrive at 19:29 or even 19:30, but I will be there, anyway.

Comment: You could say you expect to arrive **on** time, which means at the agreed moment.

Comment: @oerkelens, Can you tell the difference between `on` and `in` in this context? Or is it `in time` wrong? My point is to put emphasis in the fact that I will arrive too close to meeting time, excuse myself and ask they don't leave.

Comment: Do you want a sort of apologies for not beeing there before the meeting time ? Or you just want to say you won't be there before ?

Comment: @Random, I guess both, no? Something like `Sorry, but I'll be there very close to meeting time. Wait for me`.

Comment: _On_ time means you are there _at the agreed moment_. Not before, not after. Like _the bus is on time_. _In_ time means you will be there soon enough to attend the meeting. You may even arrive 4 hours early. (Note that a bus that leaves early is _not_ **on time** but it may eventually arrive at its destination **in time**)

Comment: @oerkelens, nice explanation. Non-english speakers have a lot of problems with prepositions like **at**, **in** and **or**. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @oerkelens Ok, so what is the difference between `just in time` and `on time` ? From your explaination, I understand the same thing...

Comment: I think the precise nuance OP seeks is a bit too complex to expect a simple word/term to cover all possibilities. I might say *[Trust me,] I **will** arrive in time - even if it's only **just** in time*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. That _nuance_ is key for my question. I tried to use google translator and its translation is `I'll be very short of time`, but I think it is not the context I'm looking for. It seems like I have some things to do, but I have not enough time. So, I opt for **on time** and/or **just in time**. According to answers and comments I got, I think they're more appropriate, unless new answers think otherwise ;)

Comment: @Random _in_ = any time before or at the exact moment of the appointment. _on_ = only at the exact moment of the appointment. Re-read the bus example. A bus that leaves in time may not be on time.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, I understand what you said before, but my question is about "just in time", not "in time"

Comment: @Random: _Just in time_ narrows down _in time_. So you won't be 4 hours early, you will be _on time_ or just before it.

Answer (score 2):

*Promptly*, *precisely*, or *on the dot* would all convey "not before" but they may not quite fit this situation.

I would probably say, "I'll make it by 19:30" or "I'll get there by 19:30" in casual conversation.  Saying *by* promises that one will not be late, but *make it [there]* or *get there* focuses the sentence on one's short arrival.

If you are uncertain or unable to promise punctuality, then add the word *try*.  "I'll try to be there by 19:30."

Another option for spoken English would be to stress the word *at*; "I'll be there ***at*** 19:30."  This verbal emphasis implies "at but not before" in a "just barely" sort of way.

Answer (score 1):

*In time* has the underlying meaning that you may be there some time before the meeting starts, but not just before it starts, but *just in time* means what you want to say:

> I'll arrive just in time for the meeting.

But

> I'm probably going to arrive right before the meeting starts.

is how I would say it in your situation, this communicates that there is no time between your arrival and the start of the meeting.

Comment: Thanks. So, as @Random pointed out, **just in time**  and **on time** has the same meaning, right?

Comment: *On time* is less specific, this may be to your advantage if you don't want to make the person expecting you worry that you'll be late.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll *only just* make it

> I'll *just about* make it

You can also change either to 'I should' to add uncertainty, i.e. you *think* you can be there at 1930, but may be a little late.